# Cassandra Multi Tenant running scripts for DB/Table creation

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, spring-data, multi-tenant

Currently when I create database/tables in `Cassandra` I have to run scripts before fetching data. But now I want to create same `Database` for each tenant in multi tenant architecture. Do I need to create database explicitly for each tenant or is there a way to create them on runtime?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Yes, you have to create them explicitly. Do you have all of them in the same keyspace / different ones? What are your requirements for isolation? One way around that is to design the schema to allow for mutliple tenants

Comment: Thanks for your response :) . Actually I don't have too many tenants so I am going for a separate database per tenant. And that is my concern, I don't want to run scripts every time a new Tenant comes. What do you suggest, should I move towards other solution like mongodb?

Comment: I don't think something you do only sometimes (adding new clients) justifies using one or another. Stuff which you'd use regularly (indexing, durability, scalability, ...) should be the deciding factor

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Welcome. If your question is answered, please post an answer with your conclusions and self accept-that so that people will see you're cool :)

Comment: Instead you can also add an answer and I will accept that ;) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to do that explicitly.

Also having database per tenant is an expensive strategy in C* (if you have a lot of tenants), this requires C* to allocate an additional memtable per each.

I'd recommend add a tenant id as a part of your row key. There's a nice video by [BlackRock guys](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=322GytEo_fE) describing what they went through in that case.